# Minimum of $ab+bc+ca$ given $a^2+b^2+c^2=2$ and $a,b,c \leq 1$

Tags: inequality

I wish to find the minimum of $ab+bc+ca$ given $a^2+b^2+c^2=2$ and $0 \leq a,b,c \leq1$.

I think the minimum is $1$ which occurs for $(1,1,0)$ and its permutations.

I have tried to substitute for $c$ in terms of $a,b$ i.e. $c=\sqrt{2-a^2-b^2}$ and then try to find the minimum of that but I get nowhere.

Please help.

Comment: Might be a bit of an overkill, but do you know about Lagrange multipliers? This should definitely get you to the solution.

Comment: No. Sadly I don't. Where can I learn about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WOLG, we suppose that $0\le c\le b\le a\le 1$, then:
$$\begin{align}
&b(a-b)\ge 0 \iff ab\ge b^2 \tag{1}\\
&c(b-c)\ge 0 \iff bc\ge c^2\tag{2}\\
&1 \ge a(a-c)\iff ca\ge a^2-1\tag{3}\\
\end{align}$$
Make the sum of $(1),(2),(3)$, we have:
$$ab+bc+ca \ge a^2+b^2+c^2 -1 = 1$$

The equality occurs if and only if $\cases{b(a-b)=0\\ c(b-c)=0\\a(a-c) = 1\\a^2+b^2+c^2=1}$ or $(a,b,c) = (1,1,0)$.
We deduce for the general case: the equality holds for $(a,b,c)$ equal to $(1,1,0)$ and its permutations.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. How did you think of this?

Comment: @tidalfire I guessed that the minimum must occur when the values of $(a,b,c)$ are on the border of its domain $[0,1]^3$ and their range ($|a-c|$) must as large as possible. And so, I created some inequality to make appear these terms $ab,bc, ca$ from $a^2,b^2, c^2$. (for example, at the first try, I wrote $a(a-b) \ge 0 \iff a^2 -ab \ge 0$ but that was not what we want, so I adjusted it by relacing the term $a$ for $b$, then we have $b(a-b)\ge 0 \iff ab \ge b^2$).